# How to change backcolor of a button when pressed and change the color to another color using another button

Tags: c#, winforms

I been working in a Cinema Booking Software for windows, it has about 20 buttons and i can't get the button code of mine to work it only turns to (GREEN) When pressed and there is no function to change it to RED after pressing booking button.

```
private Button lastButton = null;

private void button57_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Change the background color of the button that was clicked
    Button current = (Button)sender;
    current.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow;

    // Revert the background color of the previously-colored button, if any
    if (lastButton != null)
        lastButton.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

    // Update the previously-colored button
    lastButton = current;
}
```

Comment: What ist the question here? Your code should work fine, it changes the background color to green when you press a button and sets the color back for any previously clicked button. Where is your "booking button" code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem occurs when you press the same button twice in succession, because then the previous and the current buttons are the same. I would exclude this condition like this:

```
if (lastButton != null && lastButton != current) {
    lastButton.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;

    // Update the previously-colored button
    lastButton = current;
}
```